# PayPal Express checkout - does not seem to run successfully

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

So, I am trying to figure this out but cannot seem to get this right.

I am trying to integrate paypal express onto a website. I have the sandbox environment with the facilitator and buyer accounts.

I paste in the sample code and change the client values and transaction details etc... like so:

```
paypal.Button.render({

                        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

                        client: {
                            sandbox: 'My Client ID here'
                        },

                        payment: function () {

                            var env = this.props.env;
                            var client = this.props.client;

                            return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                                intent: "sale",
                                payer: { payment_method: "paypal" },
                                transactions: [
                                    {
                                        amount: { total: '14.00', currency: 'GBP' },
                                        description: "This is a payment description"
                                    },
                                ],
                                redirect_urls: {
                                    return_url: "http://somesite.com/success",
                                    cancel_url: "http://somesite.com/cancel"
                                }
                            });
                        },

                        commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

                        onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {

                            // Optional: display a confirmation page here
                            alert('confirmation here');
                            return actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
                                // Show a success page to the buyer
                                alert('success here');
                            });
                        }
                    }, '#paypal-button');
```

The issue I am facing is that when you hit the paypal button - in the popup I do not see the amount.

Then when continuing, I get an error from javascript like so:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Error: Payment Api response error:



{

    "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",

    "message": "An internal service error has occurred",

    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",

    "debug_id": "a9ceebeb96bab"

}

Error: Payment Api response error:



{

    "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",

    "message": "An internal service error has occurred",

    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",

    "debug_id": "a9ceebeb96bab"

}

   at Anonymous function (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:8325:17)

   at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1509:25)

   at SyncPromise.prototype.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1542:17)

   at SyncPromise.prototype.resolve (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1480:13)

   at Anonymous function (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1533:25)

   at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1509:25)

   at SyncPromise.prototype.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1542:17)

   at SyncPromise.prototype.resolve (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1480:13)

   at Anonymous function (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1533:25)

   at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1509:25)
```

So how the heck do I know what the error is?

**Second question:** Hopefully when this is all working with your help, how can I get back the response and determine if its a success or failure of payment along with detailed information to log it on my website and display to the user? What about custom variables like paymentID generated from my site? Can I get that information back?

Thank you

Comment: Given how spectacularly bad PayPal's documentation is (largely due to it being split across at least 5 separate overlapping/redundant integration mechanisms now), your best best is probably to ping them. They gave you an 'internal error' which means the error (or at least the lack of any reasonable messaging) is their fault. They can probably look up your request (by your api credentials) and tell you what happened. Then hopefully they can also improve their code to handle whatever bad input you supplied that tripped them up.

Comment: You might also want to switch from PayPal REST APIs to one of their somewhat-better-supported mechanisms. Their older APIs (straight up "legacy" express checkout) or their newest APIs through Braintree would probably be better bets than the REST APIs. LOTS more customers & years of effort have been invested in working out the rough edges of the former, and the latter are the ones that I believe PayPal sees as the preferred go-forward solution.

Comment: Thanks @geewiz - I am actually not doing any server side calls to their API's but only using their checkout.js. So it seems I managed to have some how got it to work (or maybe its their intermittent issue). However still, I don't know how to display the amount and description before the user buys on their lightbox/paypal window.

Comment: Oh -- you don't/can't. Since the REST APIs likely wrap the Express Checkout product, in which you send an amount to be prechecked but the final amount is not determined until you make the final execute payment call, PayPal does not display any amount in their screen. (This is so that you can do things like set final amount based on shipping details once you get the user's shipping address.)  I do believe that most forms of these checkouts should display a limited amount of description or cart information; check that you have the field names exactly correct.

Comment: PayPal has become horror. Almost every day they break entire system, and we get node.js (their back-end) fatal errors in console. So, with Express Checkout you're pretty much on your own. This is just crazy. @OP: In order to display amount, item description, SKU etc in a popup window you need to supply those data in JS script -> see the following comment -->

Comment: Here's my example which does work: https://paste.debian.net/plain/899665

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some important information for the API.
Things like AMOUNT{}, and others.

### https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/

I have a problem with this as well, I can get to the actions.payment.execute() and I get an error, _loop2 etc etc.

Comment: OP here is using Express Checkout, thus the documentation link should be: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/